# Accessing SharePoint documents from different WebApplication Zones

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, document-template

I have a SharePoint 2010 Server site (`http://shpserver:81`) that I have extended twice:

Intranet: `http://partnernet.abc.local`
Internet: `https://partnernet.abc.com`

When I am on the internet (`https://partnernet.abc.com`) and I create a new Document from within SharePoint, Word 2010 starts up and I can save the document to SharePoint. However, the default template of SharePoint (template.dotx) is coupled to this document using the absolute url `https://partnernet.abc.com/testexternproject/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Forms/template.dotx`

When I then go to the intranet (`http://partnernet.abc.local`) and I want to open this new  document from that location, Word 2010 takes very long to open the document and in the splashscreen of Word I can see that it tries to open the template file using the absolute location as mentioned above. This location is however not accessible from the intranet.

I first thought that it had something to do with the alternate accessmappings in SharePoint, but we have tried all different setups, until we realized that the location of the template was baked in the Word document with an absolute URL.

The alternate access mappings we use is (Internal URL - Zone - Public URL for Zone):

`http://shpserver:81` - Default - `http://shpserver:81`

`http://partnernet.abc.local:31081` - `intranet - http://partnernet.abc.local`

`http://partnernet.abc.local` - intranet - `http://partnernet.abc.local`

`http://partnernet.abc.com:32081` - internet - `https://partnernet.abc.com`

`https://partnernet.abc.com` - internet - `https://partnernet.abc.com`

I can not believe that we are doing something special.
What have we done wrong here?

Any suggestions are welcome.

TIA

Comment: Where is your shared device located for template.dotx type of documents

Comment: The template.dotx is a standard template of SharePoint itself and is located in the Forms-folder of the document library `https://partnernet.abc.com/testexternproject/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Forms/template.dotx` (see above)

Answer (score 0):

You said "I can see that it tries to open the template file using the absolute location as mentioned above"

> First, turn off the automatically update styles! This is a feature
>   that should not be on for routine documents or templates. It is a
>   development feature that can have some utility in
>
> Prior to distributing a document, you can attach it to the normal
>   template if you want. Everyone has one.

you can go through this link might help,

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/public-docx-with-custom-dotx-on-network-share/09c4d68b-e37a-48e0-973b-1508cb4bedf3?msgId=a65abcb4-cb43-4fcf-a805-ef6edd98846b

Comment: The template.dotx file is a standaard template of Sharepoint itself. Changing it to overcome my problem just seems strange. I was hoping that I did something wrong in the configuration area of SharePoint that would explain the described behaviour.
Anyway, thanks for your reply. It certainly is something to consider when dealing with selfmade templates.